# How to programatically chain two js functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to solve how I can to chain several js functions (two in this case). I have one javascript function to save() an another for saveAndPrint(). I need to chain the call because I need the id generated in save() to forward it for printing in the second one. Probably I just could use only one function to do both things but I'd like to learn how to do this. At the moment I just getting an 'undefined' because second function starts before the first one finishes. 
Here is the code:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var receipt = {
        documentType: 'RCI',
        expirationDate: new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        person: {id: $scope.financeDocuments[0].person.id},
        payments: getPayments(),
        promotions: [],
        creationDate: new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        compensatedDocuments: getDocumentsToPay()
    };

    financeDocumentService.save(receipt, function (response) {
        receipt = response;
        $uibModalInstance.close(response);
    }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        return receipt;
    });
};

$scope.saveAndPrint = function() {
    var document = $scope.save();                    
        $window.location.href = "#/finance/receipt_show/"+document.id;
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Off topic, but this construct looks weird to me: `financeDocumentService.save(receipt, callback).$promise` What is `financeDocumentService`? What does `financeDocumentService.save()` return? What `data` does the `$promise` resolve to? Why do you need to memorize `receipt = response` in the callback, just to be able to `return receipt` in the seemingly corresponding `$promise.then()`? I would have expected that the promise resolves to the same value you got in the callback.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, financeDocumentService is a factory for all finance documents, in example (Receipt, Credit Note, Debit Note, Invoice, etc). FinanceDocumentService.save() needs minimun data (id's) to save a document but returns a complete (refilled) object instance from database. Please, feel free to tell me if you see anything else weird. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **return** the promise:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var receipt = {
        documentType: 'RCI',
        expirationDate: new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        person: {id: $scope.financeDocuments[0].person.id},
        payments: getPayments(),
        promotions: [],
        creationDate: new moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        compensatedDocuments: getDocumentsToPay()
    };

    //RETURN the promise
    ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟  financeDocumentService.save(receipt, function (response) {
        receipt = response;
        $uibModalInstance.close(response);
    }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        return receipt;
    });
};
```

Then **chain** from the promise:

```
$scope.saveAndPrint = function() {
    var promise = $scope.save();     
    promise.then(function(receipt) {                    
        $window.location.href = "#/finance/receipt_show/"+document.id;
    });
};
```

For more information,

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)
- [You`re Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Comment: how did you underline `return`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @georgeawg!!

Comment: @baao `String.fromCharCode(863,114,863,101,863,116,863,117,863,114,863,110,863)` or `console.log("͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟".split(""))`